# Tomcat TLS session resumption in cluster

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, openssl

TLS allows session resumption via session IDs or session tickets. [This post](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2014/11/the-sad-state-of-server-side-tls-session-resumption-implementations/) shows how this can be performed in Apache web server and Nginx. Specially, Apache has a [`SSLSessionTicketKeyFile` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessionticketkeyfile) which allows the TLS session ticket to be encrypted by a specific key, rather than a key chosen randomly at startup. This is useful in cluster, where any cluster member can open a ticket encrypted by another member via a shared key.

I couldn't find a similar feature in [Tomcat TLS documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support). However, I found a method called [`setTicketKeys`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/openssl/OpenSSLSessionContext.html#setTicketKeys-byte:A-) which seems to be doing exactly what I want:

```java
public void setTicketKeys(byte[] keys)
Sets the SSL session ticket keys of this context.
Parameters:
keys - The session ticket keys
```

I also found [a class from Facebook Nifty](https://github.com/facebookarchive/nifty/blob/master/nifty-ssl/src/main/java/com/facebook/nifty/ssl/OpenSslServerConfiguration.java) which uses this function.

> My question is: I need an instance of `OpenSSLSessionContext` to call `setTicketKeys()` on. How should I get this instance?

**Edit:** If this can be done via configuration, so much the better!

Comment: You would accomplish this via some configuration element, not by writing code.

Comment: @user207421: Doing configuration is actually preferred. Could you please advise me on that?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: @user207421: Sure. See the second paragraph in my post.

Comment: @M.S.Dousti Were you able to find any solution for this?

I am trying to enable session resumption in my tomcat servers (using session tickets). I am using tomcat 9 with APR.

Can anyone tell me how to enable it? I tried multiple configs present in documentation but it is not working.

I am testing the session reuse with this command

echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -reconnect -no_ssl2 -no_ticket  2> /dev/null | grep 'New\|Reuse'

Comment: @UditJindal: Not unfortunately. I couldn't find a solution at the time I posted the question (almost 3 years ago). There might be changes to Tomcat for this purpose, but I haven't checked recently. You can also try your luck with TLS 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually documented in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Using_the_SSL_for_session_tracking_in_your_application): the main take-aways are:

- it is not doable solely via configuration, because you have to explicitely set the flag on the context listener (although you need configuration too for a connector to enable the feature!)
- there are of course caveats with proxies and SSL termination (e.g., if Tomcat terminates the SSL session, you won't be able to resume to it)
- APR connectors are not supported (yet?), only NIO(2) connectors

Comment: Sorry, but this answer states what can't be done. I need to do it, via code or config. So what I need is an answer which shows how to do it by using either or both.

Comment: Furthermore, SSL session tracking is something else: Using SSL session ID to track a user, rather than cookies.