# TLS resumption in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, openssl, apr

I want to establish tls resumption in my tomcat server, I'm using AprProtocol implementation in tomcat for tls, went through tomcat documentation but didn't find any suitable config.
Current tomcat version : 8.5

Is there any way to do that via configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer is: No. There isn't currently a way to do this via config.

See the following:

- [Tomcat TLS session resumption in cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978449/tomcat-tls-session-resumption-in-cluster).
- https://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg132408.html

Note that these are both from the same person.  The response on the mailing list suggested that the feature could be implement in Tomcat ... if someone bothered to create an IPR for it.